# Multiple .not ids - code tidy

Tags: jquery

I have multiple selects with IDs. I want to exclude these from style. My code works but there must be a cleaner way of writing this without having to repeat `.not(document.getElementById` each time?

```
function fixSelectInputs() {
    var SelectInputs = $("select").not(document.getElementById("ID1")).not(document.getElementById("ID2")).not(document.getElementById("ID3")).not(document.getElementById("ID4"));
    SelectInputs.attr("style", "width:100%!important;min-width:75px;");
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of css? Or Do you really want to do it using jQuery

Comment: It has to be jquery! dont ask  :(

Answer (score 0):

```
select:not(#ID1),select:not(#ID2),select:not(#ID3),select:not(#ID4) {
    width:100%!important;
    min-width:75px;
}
```

Comment: Remove the quotes, CSS doesn't use them

Comment: wouldn't the second (sub)selector affect the select the first subselector tried to ignore?

Answer (score 0):

simple use with `jquery` `not([id*=ID])` .They will prevent the `#ID*`'s

```
$('select:not([id*=ID])').css({
  "width": "100%!important",
  "min-width": "75px",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can exclude another selection:

```
$("select").not($("#ID1,#ID2,#ID3")).css(...)
```